# Changing label text size in code

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I have to adjust my label text size depending of the device (iPad, iPhone) and these orders just doesn't seem to work. I have my label declared in the interface, set on property as IBOutlet and synthesized. Then:

```
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Black" size:50.0];                    
label.minimumFontSize = 50.0;
```

The size just doesn't change. :S

Any advices?

Comment: I don't think `Arial Black` exists on the iPhone, could that be the problem? Tried with another font or with `systemFontOfSize:` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It may be useful to you to use:

```
[label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:35]];
```

or

```
[label setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:50.0]];
```

Comment: The first one works, thanks, really appreciate it. :) Though I don't know why the rest doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing wrong in your code except for the font you are using.
It should be :

```
   label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:50];
```

Actually **Arial Black** is not supported by iphone.
You can check the list of the fonts supported by iPhone [here](http://iosfonts.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look of the fonts you can use by Default in iOS 
 here is a link: [iOS Links](http://iosfonts.com/) http://iosfonts.com/